# FATAL: role "user" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

Trying to connect to postgres DB client - will sometimes work but from time to time I run into this error and never know how to fix it: `FATAL: role "user" does not exist` I am running a db in a container - I have a manifest file with all the db client connection details. But the username I enter per this file is not found.

Comment: "user" is a reserved word(keyword) Try to avoid using it as an identifier.